# Chrome for Testing: Website's mobile view testing switches back to basic

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-for-testing

I have a strange problem with Google's new **Chrome for Testing** application. Suddenly all my mobile test failing, because at one point the view switches back from mobile to normal. Window size stayes untouched (390x844).

It happens after a button is pressed, whose href tag looks something like this: `href="/page/example/"`, so it doesn't contains `"/mobile"`, some other buttons contain it. However, this cannot be the fault, because I tried it manually and it did not switch back like that, only when Selenium clicks it.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any ideas why this might be?